# Django: adding simple button to admin generic view

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-admin, http-referer

Django newbie here working on a pre-existing app I've inherited. I need to add a cancel/back button to the `show` (`DetailView` in Django terms, I think?) page. I know how to do this with anchor tags in HTML. However, I can't figure out *where* the HTML template is for this view! I believe it's being procedurally generated as a "generic view" or "admin" from this code in `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = 'reports'

urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /reports/
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    # ex: /reports/5/
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    # ex: /reports/5/results/
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/results$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    # ex: /reports/5/vote/
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote$', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

The bottom bar of the reports `show` / `DetailView` page contains the following values when accessed via browser:

[image: reports view bottom bar]

I'd like to add a "Cancel" button to this bar, but I can't find where I could add such a button -- I can't even find these *existing* buttons in the codebase.

An `admin/reports_admin.py` exists with some configuration that may be relevant, but I don't see an obvious place in that file where I could add this "Cancel" button.

Please help!

Comment: If you start with Django you may want to take a day or two to follow the official [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/). This will teach where the various things are defined, what’s the Django admin app, and what you can do to [customize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial07/) it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want

[Overriding admin templates | Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-overriding-templates)

as well you can override admin views, which is also described here, to add additinal functionality.